# Build FAILED when include 'cloud_firestore' plugin

Tags: firebase, flutter, visual-studio-code

I can't build my app when I include cloud_firestore as one of the plugins but if I remove it then the app runs normally. It says **Execution failed for task: ':cloud_firestore:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'**
. I've tried the solutions suggested in older post on many sites but I still get the error.

I did run `flutter doctor` too but everything is fine there

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HJ2D.jpg

```
firebase_analytics: ^8.3.4
firebase_auth: ^3.2.0
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.0
firebase_storage: ^10.1.0
```

Comment: Hi @Danial Harith do you have the `google-services.json` on your app?

Comment: @ANDREWEBARE yes I do. It should be inside android/app/ right?

Comment: correct. have you tried leaving the version of cloud_firestore unspecified? cause maybe it's having a conflict with other plugins. in my case i didn't specifie any firebase plugin version and it's working smoothly. but i did have some problems when writing the exact version i wanted

Comment: I see. But how to write it without specifying the version?

Comment: it would be something like this: `cloud_firestore:` you just have to take the numbers out

Answer (score 0):

**Enable multidex**
Open [project_folder]/app/build.gradle and add following lines.

```
defaultConfig {
    ...

    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    ...

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work too :(